# How to limit lines on a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to limit a TextView to 1 line, the length of the screen. I'm having trouble keeping it from expanding.

I've tried adding the

`android:minLines="1"
 android:maxLines="1"`

attributes to the TextView xml. This does keep the view from expanding, but this does not limit the characters of the text. For example, if I have entered the maximum number of characters in a line and proceed to add a '(' to the string, I can see the top of it printed below the first line.

Basically, I need a way to limit the amount of characters to the width of the screen. I've tried this:

```
while(txt.getLineCount() > 1) {
    txt.setText(txt.getText().subSequence(0,txt.getText().length()-1));
}
```

which doesn't work at all. I've also tried that same method with comparing the `txt.getHeight()` to the `txt.getTextSize()`.

I'm out of ideas. What can I do?

Comment: as this is a textview you are setting the text into it . right ? so control it programmatically during the settext().

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I am using setText(). I would like a method to limit the character count to only the length of the screen. As you know, each character has a different width, based on the font size. I need a method to tell me exactly when the displayed text becomes longer than the width of the View. At that point I can just say text.setText(text.getText().subSequence(0,text.getText().length-1)) to erase the character that would exceed the View width and/or create a new line

Comment: so you want to fit only one line in textview and this will change according to different screen as they differ in resolutions. right ?

Comment: Correct, but I'm only basing the View width on the screen width. At some point I will fix it to a certain dip

Answer (score 0):

If I use a textview this way it will ocupy only 1 line:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Yes but if you set the text to include more characters than can fit into the line, especially tall characters like '(', ')', '!' you can see it print the tips of those characters just inside the bottom border. Also, for the purposes of my app, I'd like to limit the CharSequence of the TextView so it can't be longer than what is visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will limit textview to single line. , if the text was more than one line it will display ... at end.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:singleline="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```